# How to use spline3D with Vue or Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, spline

I'm still new to vue and I've been trying to make an interactive site using spline 3d. When it comes to react, splinetool has it's owm library for reactjs. But I couldn't find one for Vue. I've tried to import @splinetool/runtime and export it. It worked but the 3D scene isn't catching any events. I know this isn't a good method and I'm still learning. Can someone explain how to import this as a vue component or just render it beside the vue app? And also can we use spline in Nuxtjs with same method?

**main.js**

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'

import router from './router'

import { Application } from "@splinetool/runtime";

const canvas = document.getElementById("spline3d");

    const spline = new Application(canvas);

    spline.load('splineUrl')

    .then(() => {

        const obj = spline.findObjectByName('sphere');

        objectToAnimate.emitEvent('follow');

    });

    

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Vite App</title>

  </head>

  <body>

      <canvas id="spline3d">

      </canvas>

      <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Tried to import it with @splinetool/runtime since there isn't any library for vue

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you found another way yet, but this is what worked for me.

```js
<script setup>
import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';

// template ref
const canvas = ref(null)

// spline state
const state = reactive({
    spline: {
        scene: "https://prod.spline.design/<your-spline-scene-url>/scene.splinecode",
        app: null,
        isLoaded: false,
    },
});

onMounted(async () =>{
    const app = new Application(canvas.value);
    await app.load(state.spline.scene)
    state.spline.app = app;
    state.spline.isLoaded = true;
})

<script>

<template>
    <section>
        <canvas ref="canvas" />
    </section>
</template>
```

Btw... I use the `Code export(Beta)` to get my url
I hope this helps